# How do I log in to my account?

Tags: support, help

I use stack overflow a lot and I used to have an [account](https://stackoverflow.com/users/501449?tab=stats). I never really logged in or anything, I would just fill in the form at the bottom that asked for my name an email. I recently reset my computer and so I was logged out. Is there any way I can log back in to this account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A moderator can merge your [unregistered account](https://stackoverflow.com/users/501449?tab=stats) with your newly [registered one](https://stackoverflow.com/users/560816). Pick one of your questions and click the "flag" link, choose "Requires Moderator attention", and let them know that you want the unregistered account merged

Comment: Thank you! I will have to try this. I actually have two unregistered accounts that I need to be merged with my current registered one, is this possible to? And about how long will it take?

Comment: @user Sure, just mention both in the flag. It'll take the mod about a minute, it just depends on how long before one gets to your flag (probably not long, they're pretty active)